# Union all and function based index

Tags: oracle

I have big tables with identical function based indexes. When one table is queried then query plan uses the index. When I join second table with union all then I have full scans.

I have found one working solution (WORKING JOIN WITH TABLE), but it has some limitations:

- [I cannot use ROWNUM not CONNECT BY in the x query merged to union](https://gist.github.com/gkazior/fb4cf520d4eaab38a399)
- I cannot use pipeline function in a query.

How to overcome the mentioned limitations?

I tried hints like CARDINALITY to tell that the number of record is small, and some rewrite (REWRITE, PUSH_PRED) without success. 
I cannot use partitioning since the problem is on Oracle SE.

The problem shown here is a simplification of my actual problem which is:

1. I have huge data set divided into identical tables
2. Each table contains data from a different month
3. I have a view which union all the underlying tables
4. It is [kind of partitioning style practiced on oracle before v8.0](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/A48506/partview.htm)

In real I may have adhoc queries and joins with many different tables. Thus I cannot simply push the join into a union which will be the simplest solution.

[Here is the DDL script](https://gist.github.com/gkazior/67fc759dca36b83d1ecd).

```
    -- FULL SCAN FOR IN SUBQUERY
    SELECT * FROM (
              SELECT * FROM TEST_EXPV1
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TEST_EXPV2
    )
    WHERE DECODE(Value, -1, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER(38)), 0, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER(38)), Value) IN (SELECT Id FROM test_10r)

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation            | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |            |   200K|  5078K|   916   (3)| 00:00:11 |
    |*  1 |  HASH JOIN           |            |   200K|  5078K|   916   (3)| 00:00:11 |
    |   2 |   VIEW               | VW_NSO_1   |    10 |   130 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
    |   3 |    HASH UNIQUE       |            |    10 |    30 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
    |   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST_10R   |    10 |    30 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |   5 |   VIEW               |            |  2000K|    24M|   902   (2)| 00:00:11 |
    |   6 |    UNION-ALL         |            |       |       |            |          |
    |   7 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST_EXPV1 |  1000K|  3906K|   451   (2)| 00:00:06 |
    |   8 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST_EXPV2 |  1000K|  3906K|   451   (2)| 00:00:06 |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    -- CORRECT RANGE INDEX SCAN for bound value
    SELECT * FROM (
              SELECT * FROM TEST_EXPV1
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TEST_EXPV2
    )
    WHERE DECODE(Value, -1, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER(38)), 0, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER(38)), Value) = :b1001

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                     | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |              | 20000 |   253K|   979  (10)| 00:00:12 |
    |   1 |  VIEW                         |              | 20000 |   253K|   979  (10)| 00:00:12 |
    |   2 |   UNION-ALL                   |              |       |       |            |          |
    |   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST_EXPV1   |     2 |     8 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I_TEST_EXPV1 |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |   5 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST_EXPV2   |     2 |     8 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |*  6 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I_TEST_EXPV2 |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    -- WORKING JOIN WITH TABLE
    WITH x AS (SELECT Id FROM test_10r WHERE Id BETWEEN :a AND :b)
    SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ * FROM (
              SELECT * FROM TEST_EXPV1
    UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TEST_EXPV2
    ) U, x
    WHERE DECODE(Value, -1, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER(38)), 0, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER(38)), Value) = x.id

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                        | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                 |              |     1 |    16 |   996  (11)| 00:00:12 |
    |*  1 |  FILTER                          |              |       |       |            |          |
    |*  2 |   HASH JOIN                      |              |   500 |  8000 |   996  (11)| 00:00:12 |
    |*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL             | TEST_10R     |    10 |    30 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |   4 |    VIEW                          |              |  5000 | 65000 |   993  (11)| 00:00:12 |
    |   5 |     UNION-ALL                    |              |       |       |            |          |
    |*  6 |      FILTER                      |              |       |       |            |          |
    |   7 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST_EXPV1   |  2500 | 10000 |  4192   (1)| 00:00:51 |
    |*  8 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I_TEST_EXPV1 |  4500 |       |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |*  9 |      FILTER                      |              |       |       |            |          |
    |  10 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST_EXPV2   |  2500 | 10000 |  4192   (1)| 00:00:51 |
    |* 11 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I_TEST_EXPV2 |  4500 |       |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Where are you getting those 'limitations' from?

Comment: Please see my update and [new gist](https://gist.github.com/gkazior/fb4cf520d4eaab38a399). The query is very agile: `IN` seems not to work, `ROWNUM` causes troubles. With normal indexes all works nice. Having many ad hoc queries the index is impractical.

Answer (score 3):

You're dong the UNION ALL, which is doing a full scan of both tables to get  combined result set; and only then filtering on the values from the third table.

A more usual pattern for subquery factoring is to refer to the CTE in each branch of the union:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT Id FROM test_10r)
          SELECT TEST_EXPV1.* FROM x JOIN TEST_EXPV1
          ON DECODE(Value, -1, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER(38)), 0, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER(38)), Value) = x.Id
UNION ALL SELECT TEST_EXPV2.* FROM x JOIN TEST_EXPV2
          ON DECODE(Value, -1, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER(38)), 0, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER(38)), Value) = x.Id;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                          
| Id  | Operation                     | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                                                                                          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                          
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |              |    32 |   224 |    66   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                          
|   1 |  UNION-ALL                    |              |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                          
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                |              |    16 |   112 |    33   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                          
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL          | TEST_10R     |    10 |    30 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                          
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST_EXPV1   |     2 |     8 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                          
|*  5 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I_TEST_EXPV1 |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                          
|   6 |   NESTED LOOPS                |              |    16 |   112 |    33   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                          
|   7 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL          | TEST_10R     |    10 |    30 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                          
|   8 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST_EXPV2   |     2 |     8 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                          
|*  9 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I_TEST_EXPV2 |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is of course sound solution, unfortunately impractical in my actual problem. Please see my edit.

Comment: @GrzegorzKazior - not entirely sure I follow; you're really trying to join your view (which is a union-all of the 'partition' tables) to `test_10r`, or at least filter based on it's contents? Which means you can't move the join condition into each union branch?

Comment: ... and with a view, Matthew McPeak's `PUSH_PRED` version still does an index range scan (also 11.2.0.4). At least as long as each branch of the union is only against a single table and follows the other rules from the doc you linked to; were the 'limitations' you talked about on the union branches rather than the 'x' CTE, in which case I misunderstood you? Are your union branches actually much more complicated than you've suggested?

Comment: test_10r is only a one of many tables. The view may be joined with adhoc queries and this is the problem. The view was created as a replacement for oracle ee partition for smaller installation and works nice - unfortunately not for  FBI.

Comment: Strange but it works [now with `ROWNUM` but I have to user `WITH` and `BETWEEN` predicate. It does not work with your `LEFT JOIN`] (https://gist.github.com/gkazior/fb4cf520d4eaab38a399)

This is the limitation I mentioned.

Comment: @GrzegorzKazior - the left join works too with `where small.id between :a and :b` and FIRST_ROWS. Interesting.

Comment: ...and this is the issue here. One ad hoc query and my FBI makes my disks spinning and customer impatient.

Comment: It sounds similar to bug 14669785, but that's supposedly fixed in 11.2.0.4, and the workaround for that doesn't seem to affect this problem. Also a bit like some others. You might need to raise an SR to get this specific scenario investigated.

Answer (score 3):

Pushing predicates into a `UNION ALL` can be temperamental.  Try this:

```
SELECT /*+ PUSH_PRED(v) */ *
FROM   (SELECT * FROM test_expv1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM test_expv2) v INNER JOIN test_10r ON
        (DECODE(Value, -1, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER(38)), 0, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER(38)), Value)) = test_10r.id;
```

Here are my results for the above query from an 11.2.0.4 instance, using the OP's DDL:

```
SQL_ID  df6dvkgjwjsq1, child number 1
-------------------------------------
SELECT /*+ PUSH_PRED(v) */ * FROM   (SELECT * FROM test_expv1         
UNION ALL         SELECT * FROM test_expv2) v INNER JOIN test_10r ON    
     (DECODE(Value, -1, CAST(NULL AS NUMBER(38)), 0, CAST(NULL AS 
NUMBER(38)), Value)) = test_10r.id

Plan hash value: 191389749

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name         | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |              |      1 |        |     16 |00:00:00.01 |      69 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                  |              |      1 |   2000K|     16 |00:00:00.01 |      69 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL            | TEST_10R     |      1 |     10 |     10 |00:00:00.01 |      22 |
|   3 |   VIEW                         |              |     10 |     32 |     16 |00:00:00.01 |      47 |
|   4 |    UNION ALL PUSHED PREDICATE  |              |     10 |        |     16 |00:00:00.01 |      47 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST_EXPV1   |     10 |    158 |      8 |00:00:00.01 |      24 |
|*  6 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I_TEST_EXPV1 |     10 |      2 |      8 |00:00:00.01 |      16 |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST_EXPV2   |     10 |    158 |      8 |00:00:00.01 |      23 |
|*  8 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I_TEST_EXPV2 |     10 |      2 |      8 |00:00:00.01 |      15 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   6 - access("TEST_EXPV1"."SYS_NC00002$"="TEST_10R"."ID")
   8 - access("TEST_EXPV2"."SYS_NC00002$"="TEST_10R"."ID")
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me in 11.2.0.4.  What do you mean "adding a `= value` to the join condition"?  The query I posted was complete and would run against his DDL with no modifications.  Did you get the whole thing I posted?  (You need to scroll to see all of it...). I updated my answer with the results I get.

Comment: Yes, `PUSH_PRED` solves the problem in that case. When you add `test_10r BETWEEN :a AND :b` it does not require `PUSH_PRED`.
[See my new gist](https://gist.github.com/gkazior/fb4cf520d4eaab38a399).

Adhoc queries are fragile which is my actual problem.